# How come this doesn't work?

Tags: jquery

Ok so I'm new to jQuery and I have been practicing on codecademy and I thought it was pretty cool so I tried to make my own version on my computer but it doesn't work! I think I might have done something really dumb or its just my computer (Its old :p).

### **Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery test</title>
    <style>
    div {
height: 60px;
width: 100px;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #69D2E7;
}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>   
</body>
</html>
```

### **script.html**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('div').mouseenter(function() {
    $('div').fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
$('div').mouseleave(function() {
    $('div').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
});
});
```

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Surely you can dream up a title which _actually_ summarizes the problem you're facing. What exactly is the problem, anyway?

Comment: You need to load jQuery in order to use it.

Comment: Ok, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete simple jQuery demo

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content" style="display: none">
            <h1>Hello jQuery</h1>
        </div>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                $( '#content' ).fadeIn();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, instead of simply specifying selectors like `$( 'div' )` it is preferred to use id like `$( '#divID' )` or perhaps classes like `$( '.divClass' )`

Answer (score 0):

Put a script src to jQuery above your other script. Like so

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that you have not included jQuery into your document.

http://jsfiddle.net/patrickhaede/MgGh7/

Have a look here. This is what you would have to include into a script tag in your header.

```
 //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
```

In the js fiddle you can actually see on the left hand side that I have included the jQuery library and your code is working :)